# Specify VARCHAR/NVARCHAR length in CallableStatement (mssql-jdbc driver)

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I am using SQL Server 2017 Ent with Spring Framework (5.3.19) and mssql-jdbc driver (8.4.0.jre8). Is there a way to specify VARCHAR/NVARCHAR length in CallableStatement ?

**Pseudo-code**

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = 
conn.prepareCall(concatenatedCallableStmt (index,paramVal));

concatenatedCallableStmt (int index,Object parameterValue) 
{
   case Types.VARCHAR:
      //stmt.setString(index, String.valueOf(parameterValue));
       stmt.setObject(index,parameterValue,Types.VARCHAR ,String.valueOf(parameterValue).length());
    break;
}
```

Final `CallableStatement` for this execution :

`{? = CALL [dbo].[<SP_NAME>] (@P1=?,@P2=?,@P3=?,@P4=?)}`

All the params are getting submitted with nvarchar(4000) to the database if I use `setString` or `setObject`

**Profiler screenshot:**
[image: JDBC_CallableStatement_All_VARCHAR_Params_4000]

The SP in the DB has `VARCHAR(60)` for the concerned parameters.
[image]

Is there a way I could specify the length of the parameters (like `varchar(60)` instead of `nvarchar(4000)`) in `setString/setObject` or any other way?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , thank you! That's what I found too. In fact, the [mssql-jdbc driver 
 Parameter.java Line 771](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/Parameter.java) actually has a code path where there concatenate a "length" , just that, the length is a _static final variable_ I think. May be we can make this accept lengths?